# how can i make another java class for revmob ads and then simply call that class into any Activity?

Tags: android, class, revmob

how can i make another java class for revmob ads in android studio and then simply call that class into any Activity? is it possible to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes for decreasing complexity you can create separate RevMobHelper class.

Take a look of this [class](https://github.com/itsabhiaryan/AdService-LibGDX/blob/master/android/src/com/its/adservice/RevMobHelper.java)